# How to search string in multiple files? if doesnot exist then display file name

Tags: linux, shell

I have a scenario

where I want to search a keyword in multiple files

if the keyword does not exist then display the file name

keyword need to search is `'$$DEMO_STUDENT_NAME'`

Command not working ...

```
grep "$$DEMO_STUDENT_NAME" /d/demo/
```

Comment: Bear in in mind that ```$$```  in Bash is a variable that holds the PID of the current shell. If you are using that in your command/script inside double quotes, the results will probably never be what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code working as expected 
Slightly modified taking reference from @dash-o

```
_Dir='/d/d1/Demo'
_P='/d/files'

find $_Dir -type f -iname "*.txt"  >> $_P/Demo.csv

for file in `cat $_P/Demo.csv` 
do
    if ! fgrep -q '$$DEMO_STUDENT_NAME' $file
    then
        echo "$file" >> $_P/keyword_not_found.csv 
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$$DEMO_STUDENT_NAME` is literally the word you're looking for and not a mispelled environment variable name, use this instead (pay attention to the single quotes):

```
grep -vrl '$$DEMO_STUDENT_NAME' /d/demo/
```

or this:

```
grep -rlL '$$DEMO_STUDENT_NAME' /d/demo/
```

Here is a proof of concept:

```
$ mkdir temp
$ echo 'teste' > temp/file1
$ echo 'teste' > temp/file2
$ echo 'teste' > temp/file3
$ echo 'work' > temp/file4
$ grep -vrl teste temp/
temp/file4
$ grep -rlL teste temp/
temp/file4
$ grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 2.20
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
```

Comment: did you mean grep -rL ?

Comment: @accdias => above command display filename which contain the keyword. I want to display the filename which does not contain the particular keyword

Comment: Nops. Both displays files that does not match ```${DEMO_STUDENT_NAME}``` variable contents.

Comment: Added a proof of concept demoing that.

Comment: Please try to add another, irrelevant string into each file

Comment: I just did it and I've got the same results. Can you share the file contents and the value of ```$DEMO_STUDENT_NAME``` you are using to test that?

Comment: Bear in in mind that ```$$```  in Bash is a variable that holds the PID of the current shell. If you are using that in your command/script inside double quotes, the results will probably never be what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the file list in FLIST, you can find files without a match. Look for -L/--files-without-match

```
grep --files-without-match '$$DEMO_STUDENT_NAME' $FLIST
```

If you have older grep, without --files-without-match option , you can use the following loop:

```
for file in $FLIST ; do
    if ! fgrep -q '$$DEMO_STUDENT_NAME' $file ; then
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: => need to change line which is $FLIST => to `cat $FLIST`

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `grep -c` (then checking against trailing ':0') for such kind of task:

```
grep  -c  $PATTERN $FILE_LIST |  grep :0\$   | sed -e s/:0\$//
```

Comment: => I have added the solution refer that too

Answer (score 0):

One may want finding a file set complement for such a task:

```
(grep -l $PATTERN $FILE_LIST ; ls $FILE_LIST ) | sort | uniq -u
```